# WPF project - Entity Framework Injection vs Application Property

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, architecture

I am very new to WPF.

I am trying to figure out pros/cons of various architecture patterns in WPF, while creating an application designed to interact with a database.

The application begins with a master window, which contains various buttons which load other windows which each perform CRUD operations on different tables within that DB.

I am wondering about the merits and disadvantages of 3 possible approaches:

1) Instantiate a new entity instance within the constructor for each window

2) Each window have a have a constructor which supports dependency injection of the entity object. Every time the master window instantiates a new window object, it injects its own instance of the entity.

3) As per [WPF Data Binding Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) Create public ObjectResult properties on a class which inherits from application, and link to this/these properties in the

```
<Window.Resources><CollectionViewSource>
```

Tag of the various windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency Injection is the best option giving you most flexibility...

However, you shouldn't inject something as specific as the entity object but some service provider instead which would be a specific implementation of a service `Interface` and would not use the entity object directly but a Model instead which would abstract away the data access specifics giving you loose coupling benefits...